# How do I convert an underscored pointer to a char array into camelCasing?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that will convert a "word_string" to "wordString". However, my output from the code below is "wordSttring". I'm having trouble skipping to the next element of the array after I replace the undescore with the uppercase of the next element. Any suggestions?

---

```
void convert_to_camel(char* phrase){
int j =0;
for(int i=0;i<full_len-1;i++){
    if(isalphanum(phrase[i])){
        phrase[j] = phrase[i];
        j++;
        length++;
    }
}
int flag = 0;
char new[50];
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){

    if(phrase[i]== '95'){
        flag = 1;
    }
    if(flag ==1){
        new[i] = toUpper(phrase[i+1]);
        i++;
        new[i] = phrase[i+1];
        flag = 0;
    }
    else{
        new[i] = phrase[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to have one more index variable (`j`) to for copying.

Comment: What is `full_len` ? what is `word` ? Please provide a complete code example.

Comment: Consider a string like "a_very_new_and_exciting_string". What should it convert to? Place the original and the converted string one under another. What can you say about offsets between their corresponding characters?

Answer (score 2):

All other solutions presented so far turn `"_"` into an empty string and remove `_` from the end of the string.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void to_camel_case(char *str)  // pun_intended
{
    for (size_t i = 0, k = 0; str[i]; ++i, ++k)
    {
        while (k && str[k] == '_' && str[k + 1])                           // 1)
            str[k] = k - 1 ? toupper((char unsigned)str[++k]) : str[++k];  // 2)
        str[i] = str[k];
    }
}
```

1. Skip consecutive `'_'`. Make sure to leave at least one at the beginning and one at the end of the string if present.
2. Replace `'_'` with the next character, capitalized if needed.

Comment: The `(int)` cast in `str[k] = toupper((int)str[++k]);` isn't protection against accented characters with a signed plain `char` type (character values which convert to a negative `int` when promoted).  You need to cast to `(unsigned char)`.  Casting to `int` leaves the negative character value as a negative integer value, and the only negative value that can be passed safely is EOF.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the removing `_` properly for that you need one more loop index(`j`).

And you don't need one more loop to remove the non alpha numeric chars it can be done with `_` loop only,
also you need to terminate the `string` once trimming is completed otherwise your `string` will have junk chars.

```
void toCamelCase(char* phrase){
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(phrase);i++){

        if(phrase[i] != '_' && isalnum(phrase[i])){ //Copy Alpha numeric chars not including _.
            phrase[j++] = phrase[i];
        }
        else if(phrase[i] == '_'){
            phrase[j++] = toupper(phrase[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
     }
      phrase[j] = '\0'; //Terminate the string
 }
```

> Note::This method does not handle consecutive `_`(`word____string`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might help :

```
void toCamelCase(char* phrase){
    int length = strlen(phrase);
    int res_ind = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++) { 
        // check for underscore in the sentence 
        if (phrase[i] == '_') { 
            // conversion into upper case 
            phrase[i + 1] = toupper(s[i + 1]); 
            continue; 
        } 
        // If not space, copy character  
        else 
            phrase[res_ind++] = s[i];         
    } 
    phrase[res_ind] = '\0'; 
}
```

Comment: The `continue;` doesn't provide much benefit since if it is omitted, the code will continue on the next cycle of the loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in your current implementation you are trying to use `new` character array to store the processed string but you won't be able to use it outside that function since it is local variable and its end of life is the very moment the flow exits that function.

Here is my proposal for such function:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 50

// assuming that 'str' is a null terminated string
void to_camel_case(char *str)
{
    int idx = 0;
    int newIdx = 0;
    int wasUnderscore = 0;

    // just to be on the safe side
    if (!str || strlen(str) >= MAX_STR_LEN)
        return;

    while (str[idx])
    {
        if (str[idx] == '_')
        {
            idx++;
            // no copy in this case, just raise a flag that '_' was met
            wasUnderscore = 1;
        }
        else if (wasUnderscore)
        {
            // next letter after the '_' should be uppercased
            str[newIdx++] = toupper(str[idx++]);
            // drop the flag which indicates that '_' was met
            wasUnderscore = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // copy the character and increment the indices
            str[newIdx++] = str[idx++];
        }
    }

    str[newIdx] = '\0';
}
```

I [tested](https://ideone.com/CzBQru) it with some inputs and this is what I got:

```
String hello_world became helloWorld
String hello___world became helloWorld
String hel_lo_wo_rld__ became helLoWoRld
String __hello_world__ became HelloWorld
```